# Exercise II.2.2: Prove that $\lim \dfrac{n^3}{2^n} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to solve *Problem II.2.2* in textbook **Analysis I** by Amann/Escher.

> [image]

Could you please verify whether my attempt on (b) and (c) is fine or it contains logical gaps/errors?

---

**My attempt:**

From binomial theorem, we have $$2^n = (1+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} = {n \choose 4} + \sum_{k=0 \atop k\neq 4}^n {n \choose k} = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) + \sum_{k=0 \atop k\neq 4}^n {n \choose k}$$

As a result, $$\begin{aligned} \lim \dfrac{n^3}{2^n} &= \lim \dfrac{n^3}{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) + \sum_{k=0 \atop k\neq 4}^n {n \choose k}} \\ &= \lim \dfrac{1}{n \left( 1-\dfrac{1}{n} \right) \left(1-\dfrac{2}{n} \right) \left(1-\dfrac{3}{n} \right) + \dfrac{\sum_{k=0 \atop k\neq 4}^n {n \choose k}}{n^3}} \\ &= \lim \dfrac{1}{n + \dfrac{\sum_{k=0 \atop k\neq 4}^n {n \choose k}}{n^3}} = 0\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Looks fine to me., though your notation is perhaps a bit sloppy.  You just wrote $\lim$ where you mean to write $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$.  As you work with more than one variable or work with real limits instead, that distinction becomes crucial and it is good to be in the habit of labeling it correctly.

Comment: Also, $\binom{n}{4} = \dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{\color{red}{24}}$.  Although the coefficients don't matter too much here, they still should not have been forgotten.

Comment: Thank you so much @JMoravitz ;) It's my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but you can be more concrete and more simple:

It is $2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}>\binom{n}{4}$ for $n$ big enough.

$\binom{n}{4}=\frac{n!}{4!(n-4)!}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}<\frac{n^4}{24}$

We can stipulate like this:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^3}{2^n}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^3}{n^4/24}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{24}{n}=0$

Because you have certainly already proven, that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n=0$